# Form data to object to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form. When I click the <kbd>save</kbd> button, I want to create an object from the data and pass that info to HTML elements on the same page (div.form_content).

I decided, instead of creating a variable for each HTML element to create an array of HTML elements.  I know the first HTML element is going to contain the first object property, the second html element will contain the second obj property, and so on...

What I have done below seems a little repetitive and not very DRY, and I was wondering if someone could recommend a better way.  For example, if my form has to grow to 12 input fields, what I am doing now would be pretty clunky.  I tried running a loop to prevent the line-by-line assignments, but couldn't figure it out. (By the way, I needed to create an object from the form data because I will need to stringify it to JSON notation to pass to the server, but I got that part.)

```
$('#save').click(function() {

    var form_Array = $('form').serializeArray();

    // Create an Array of HTML elements
    var el_Array = $('div.form_content').children();

    // create empty object
    var obj = {};   

    // loop through serialized form object and assign new object keys from this.name and their values from this.value
    $.each(form_Array, function() {
        obj[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    // populate the html elements with contents of the newly created object
    $(el_Array[0]).html(obj.fname);
    $(el_Array[1]).html(obj.lname);
    $(el_Array[2]).html(obj.phone);
    $(el_Array[3]).html(obj.fax);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say give your "output" elements a `data-*` attribute that matches the name of the form value it should contain. For instance:

```
​<div​​​ class="form_content">
    <div data-key="fname"></div>
    <div data-key="lname"></div>
    <div data-key="phone"></div>
    <div data-key="fax"></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  var values = $('form').serializeArray(),
      output = $('#values');

  $.each(values, function() {
    output.children("[data-key='" + this.name + "']").text(this.value);
  });
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rm7jK/1/)

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked great...sorry, don't have enough cred to upvote